# JPA @ElementCollection of @Embeddable items with @AttributeOverride

Tags: java, jpa, mariadb, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
  @Column(name="str")
  private String street;

  @Column(name="nr")
  private int number;

  // getters/setters
}
```

and the Address @Embeddable is used in two places in the User entiy as: Address User.mainAddress and List User.otherAddresses:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(
      name="street", 
      column=@Column(name="main_user_address_street")),
    @AttributeOverride(
      name="number", 
      column=@Column(name="main_user_address_number"))
  })
  private Address mainAddress;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
    name="user_addresses", 
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(
      name="street", 
      column=@Column(name="other_user_address_street")),
    @AttributeOverride(
       name="number", 
       column=@Column(name="other_user_address_number"))
  })
  private List<Address> otherAddresses;

  // getters/setters
}
```

This creates tables as follow:

```
user(ID, main_user_address_street, main_user_address_number)
user_addresses(nr, str, user_id)
```

Question:

@AttributeOverrides for User.otherAddresses seems they are ignored, I was expecting that the user_addresses table would have the column structure as:

```
user_addresses(other_user_address_number, other_user_address_street, user_id)
```

Am I missing sth or is this the expected result?

Dependencies:

- org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence/2.2.0
- org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.7.1
- org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.2.4
- java version: 1.8

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your expectations. Looks like your JPA provider (which one?) is not respecting the JPA spec. I have similar cases using DataNucleus and it respects the overrides for embeddables in a `CollectionTable`.

Comment: my jpa-provider: eclipselink and jdbc-driver: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Comment: so report a bug on your provider (unless there already is one that they haven't been bothered to look at)

Comment: Seems like this was reported to them long ago, and they can't be bothered fixing it. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413985  Seems also that the "JPA TCK" has no test for this part of the JPA spec, and the JPA provider you use is not "JPA compliant"

Comment: Thanks @BillyFrost, why do u say that my provider is not JPA compliant? In the doc (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/blocks002.htm) is written: "EclipseLink provides a complete, JPA-compliant JPA implementation"

Comment: As I've already said above, `AttributeOverride` is intended for just what you are doing, and EclipseLink is apparently ignoring it, so no it does not pass that part of the JPA spec